# Blocking requests to the IP

Tags: lighttpd

I have some visitors who are accessing my web-server(lighttpd) via the Ipv4 or Ipv6 IP. I want to block this somehow, and accept only requests by a domain name.

```
2018-10-10 18:24:46: (response.c.351) Request-URI     :  /
2018-10-10 18:24:46: (response.c.352) URI-scheme      :  http
2018-10-10 18:24:46: (response.c.353) URI-authority   :  xxx.243.48.85
2018-10-10 18:24:46: (response.c.354) URI-path (raw)  :  /
2018-10-10 18:24:46: (response.c.355) URI-path (clean):  /
2018-10-10 18:24:46: (response.c.356) URI-query       :
```

what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a condition with allowed hosts and deny everything which does not match: 

    `server.modules += ("mod_access")
    $HTTP["host"] !~ "^(my-vhost|other-vhost)$" { url.access-deny = ("") }`

Alternatively, create a condition which matches the IP addresses in $HTTP["host"] or an empty string, and deny access.  This is more difficult to get correct.

Using an explicit allow list (the first option above) and denying everything else is often the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the link https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_configuration, You need to create a rule to accept a http request only when the `$HTTP["host"] == <your_webserver_domain_name>` else simple give a `403 Forbidden` Response